# Initializing multiple data structures inside of each other c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, constructor, initialization

I was looking for help on how to initialize the following data structure inside of my constructor for backtracking:

```
stack<tuple<vector<set<int> >, int, int> > record;  //none of the structures have been initialized yet
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us this code in context, and share a few of the things you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a complex type like that, it is helpful to divide the type into fundamental types before figuring out how to initialize it.

Divide your type into fundamental types, it looks like:

```
stack<tuple<vector<set<int> >, int, int> > record;
      ^                                 ^
      |                                 |

      tuple<vector<set<int> >, int, int>
            ^                ^ ^  ^ ^  ^
            |                | |  | |  |

            vector<set<int> >
                   ^       ^
                   |       |

                   set<int>
                       ^  ^
                       |  |
```

To initialize an object of such a type, you'll have to figure out how to build up from the constituent fundamental types.

Initialize an `int`.

```
int a{0};
```

Initialize a `set<int>`.

```
set<int> b{1, 2};
```

Initialize a `vector<set<int>>`.

```
vector<set<int>> c{ {1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 8} };
```

Initialize a `tuple<vector<set<int>>, int, int>`.

```
tuple<vector<set<int>>, int, int> d{ { {1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 8} }, 10, 20};
```

However, you cannot use the same strategy to initialize `stack` since `std::stack` does not have a constructor that you can use like:

```
stack<int> e{1, 3, 5};
```

That means, you can't initialize a `stack<tuple<vector<set<int>>, int, int>>` as:

```
stack<tuple<vector<set<int> >, int, int> > record
{
   {{ {1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 8} }, 10, 20},
   {{ {1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 8} }, 10, 20}
};
```

Your only choice is to default construct `record` and add items to it.

```
stack<tuple<vector<set<int> >, int, int> > record;
using item_type = decltype(record)::value_type;
record.push(item_type{{ {1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 8} }, 10, 20});
record.push(item_type{{ {1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 8} }, 10, 20});
```